# COMO PUEDO ACTUALIZAR DATOS AUTOMATICAMENTE EN MI BASE DE DATOS

Tags: php, postgresql, cron

Bueno tengo un sistema donde tengo el apartado de notificaciones con un boton para ver la notificacion y lo que quiero es que cada vez que el usuario vea su notificacion se quede con el estado="Activo" durante 15 dias y pasado ese tiempo se actualice automaticamente el estado de Activo a Inactivo la unica forma que se me ocurrio fue usar triggers:

```html
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION agregar_estado_inactivo()
  RETURNS trigger AS $BODY$
 
begin
    
    
    UPDATE public.notificaciones set estado='INACTIVO'  where id = new.id and created_at < created_at  - interval '15 days';   
    return NEW;
END $BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Un trigger se ejecuta cada vez que hay un cambio en la tabla asociada al trigger... vos lo que queres es un tarea programada diaria?

Comment: para eso se usa cron o cronjobs, programalo para que todos los dias en la mañana a las 00:00 pase todas las notificaciones con mas de 15 dias a inactivo...

Comment: esto no tiene que ver con javascript; ni tiene que ver con trigger el trigger no se ejecutara automaticamente siempre dependera de un evento de usuario; por ejemplo encadenarlo al loggin ... lo cual no correcto... hay que separar la logica de negocio del sistema del apartado de seguridad y login en este caso...

Comment: En general, los triggers se desaconsejan: yo sólo los uso como ultima opcion cuando quiero una solución rapida. Empezar una aplicación usando triggers quizá no es la mejor opcion.

Comment: Los triggers no se disparan a petición del usuario. Necesitas algo en lógica de negocio que haga la actualización del estado y algo en la interfaz que detecte la inactividad y lance la petición para correr lo que implementaste.